# How to use an older Sears Craftsman pad sander

Tags: sander

I have a 1/2 sheet pad sander and I can't find the user manual online.

Sears Craftsman Model p11616.

I also can't figure out how to attach the sand paper. It us designed to use adhesive and non-adhesive backed paper.

Below is a picture of the clasp to secure the paper and I can't make sense if it. It is just shredding the ends of the paper. I can't find a logical way for the full width of the paper to be secured.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When rotated, that lever should lift the bar it is mounted to. You then slip the edge of the sandpaper under the bar and rotate the lever back, the bar will pinch the paper under it. Pull the paper taut and repeat on the other side of the sander to secure.